# Syntax highlighting in the terminal

Tags: terminal, colors, syntax-highlighting

Lots of programming-oriented editors will colorize source code. Is there a command that will colorize source code for viewing in the terminal?

I could open a file with `emacs -nw` (which opens in the terminal instead of popping up a new window), but I'm looking for something that works like `less` (or that works *with* `less -R`, which passes through color escape sequences in its input).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

With [`highlight`](http://www.andre-simon.de) on a terminal that supports the same colour escape sequences as [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
highlight -O xterm256 your-file | less -R
```

With [`ruby-rouge`](https://github.com/jayferd/rouge):

```
rougify your-file | less -R
```

With [`python-pygments`](http://pygments.org/):

```
pygmentize your-file | less -R
```

With [GNU `source-highlight`](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/):

```
source-highlight -f esc256 -i your-file | less -R
```

You can also use `vim` as a pager with the help of `macros/less.sh` script shipped with `vim` (see `:h less` within `vim` for details):

On my system:

```
sh /usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/less.sh your-file
```

Or you could use any of the syntax highlighters that support HTML output and use `elinks` or `w3m` as the pager (or `elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 3 | less -R`) like with [GNU `source-highlight`](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/):

```
source-highlight -o STDOUT -i your-file | elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 3 | less -R
```

Comment: Highlight can convert text into SVG/HTML, which is very exciting.

Answer (score 14):

I use GNU `source-highlight` combined with `less -R` for this. Add the following lines to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc`, for example):

```
cless(){
 LESSOPEN='| source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc256 -o STDOUT -i %s 2>/dev/null ' less -R "$@"
}
```

That should automatically color source code according to the language used and, if it can't, it will launch `less` on its input directly.

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in colors in `less` more generally, you might want to look at `lesspipe.sh`. See, for example, http://freecode.com/projects/lesspipe.

> lesspipe.sh is an input filter for the pager less as described in less's man page. The script runs under a ksh-compatible shell (e.g. bash, zsh) and allows you to use less to view files with binary content, compressed files, archives, and files contained in archives.

It will also colorize shell scripts, perl scripts, etc. similarly to a text editor, but without the use of any "preprocessing" program to do the colorizing.

Comment: Thanks! I think `lesspipe.sh` is what I was trying to remember before I posted the question...

Answer (score 4):

You can use bat: https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

```
bat your_file
```

acts as `cat` but pretty-prints the file contents, including file name, line numbers and syntax highlighting. There are options for piping colorized output e.g. to `less`. By default, when the output is piped, it behaves like `cat` and just copies the data from `stdin` to `stdout`.

Unlike GNU `source-highlight` which uses the file extension for language recognition, bat recognizes the syntax from the input itself and therefore can read piped input without explicitly specifying the language.

Answer (score 2):

I enjoy simplicity and I use nano text editor, in this case I usually proceed as follow:

check witch syntax highlight is available: 
`ls -la /usr/share/nano/`

include it in my nanorc file with following command, or by doing it manually

```
echo 'include /usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc' >> ~/.nanorc
```

---

about `less` I suggest to give a look at [this page](https://www.meejah.ca/blog/less-pygments)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package, [**e2ansi**](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi), that provides
syntax highlighting support for pagers like `more` and `less`.

The package use the mother of all text editors, [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs), to
perform the actual syntax highlighting. As an added bonus, all other
conversions normally performed by Emacs -- like uncompressing files --
is also performed.

## Example

The following is the result of viewing a file using `less` and
`e2ansi`:

[image: Example]

## Configuration

The package provides a command-line tool `e2ansi-cat` that starts
Emacs in batch mode, opens files, syntax highlight them, and renders
the result using ANSI sequences.

You can integrate this into `less` by setting the following variables
to, for example (the location of your init file may vary):

```
export "LESSOPEN=||-/usr/local/emacs --batch -Q -l ~/.emacs -l bin/e2ansi-cat %s"
export "LESS=-r"
alias "more=less -X -E"
```

In the configuration above, `less` restores the original terminal
window content whereas `more` simply output new content after the
prompt.

Note: If you use an old version of `less`, it might not support the
`||` or the `-` syntax, in which case you may need to use simply
`LESSOPEN=|/usr/local/emacs ...`.

## Using `less` in pipes

The "-" character in `LESSOPEN` indicates that the input filter should
also be used when piping text into `less`. In this case, Emacs can
only rely on text itself (and not a file name). Fortunately, Emacs
provides a system for this. In addition, the provided file file
`e2ansi-magic.el` sets up additional file types. For example:

[image: Pipe example]

## Why use Emacs?

- Emacs has support for virtually all programming languages and
  structured text formats. In most cases, the syntax highlighting
  support is excellent.
- You can easily add support for more languages and formats, or modify
  existing packages to suit you needs.
- Emacs support color themes. When using `e2ansi`, the colors in the
  theme is preserved when viewing a file in `less`. You can pick a
  suitable color theme from a number of sources, or design your own.
- If you use Emacs as your editor of choice, you will get the same
  highlighting in the editor as you get when viewing a file using
  `less` (minus limitations in ANSI sequence format and the terminal
  window).
- `less` will take advantage of Emacs features that perform automatic
  conversion, for example uncompressing files. In fact, you can teach
  Emacs to perform any kind of conversion like automatically convert a
  binary file to human readable form using an external tool.
- You can view files located on other machines by using Emacs' syntax
  for remote access like `/USER@HOST:FILENAME`.

## Useful links

- `e2ansi` is distributed on [Melpa](http://www.melpa.org) and can be installed using
  the standard Emacs package system
- `e2ansi` is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi)
- The `e2ansi` page on the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/e2ansi)
- The home of [`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less).

## Operating system notes

- On MS Windows, the console does not natively support ANSI sequences.
  Fortunately, the `less` application is capable of rendering them. I
  am not aware of any contemporary binary distribution of `less` for
  MS Windows and the provided build files is hard to use. Fortunately,
  it's easy to build `less` using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), see [this text](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi/blob/master/doc/LessWindows.md) for
  details.
- OS X distributes an ancient version of `less`. Fortunately, it's
  easy to build a modern version directly from the source.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Stéphane Chazelas** suggestion, I make a bash function to use `highlight` show Syntax highlight, put it into .bashrc or so on. It works great, fast and effective.

```
s(){ highlight --force -O ansi $1 | /usr/bin/less -R; }
```

highlight support **202 language syntax format**. see `highlight --list-scripts=langs`.

Answer (score 0):

Themes, to use with the -s param:

**Example**

```
highlight -l --out-format=html -s neon --syntax=php < in.txt 1> out.html
```

List themes available on your system:

```
ls /usr/share/highlight/themes
```

---

```
acid.theme         darkbone.theme           edit-matlab.theme     maroloccio.theme    rdark.theme
aiseered.theme     darkness.theme           edit-msvs2008.theme   matrix.theme        relaxedgreen.theme
andes.theme        darkslategray.theme      edit-nedit.theme      moe.theme           rootwater.theme
anotherdark.theme  darkspectrum.theme       edit-purebasic.theme  molokai.theme       seashell.theme
autumn.theme       denim.theme              edit-vim-dark.theme   moria.theme         solarized-dark.theme
baycomb.theme      dusk.theme               edit-vim.theme        navajo-night.theme  solarized-light.theme
bclear.theme       earendel.theme           edit-xcode.theme      navy.theme          sourceforge.theme
biogoo.theme       easter.theme             ekvoli.theme          neon.theme          tabula.theme
bipolar.theme      edit-anjuta.theme        fine_blue.theme       nightshimmer.theme  tcsoft.theme
blacknblue.theme   edit-bbedit.theme        freya.theme           night.theme         the.theme
bluegreen.theme    edit-eclipse.theme       fruit.theme           nuvola.theme        vampire.theme
breeze.theme       edit-emacs.theme         github.theme          olive.theme         whitengrey.theme
bright.theme       edit-fasm.theme          golden.theme          orion.theme         xoria256.theme
camo.theme         edit-flashdevelop.theme  greenlcd.theme        oxygenated.theme    zellner.theme
candy.theme        edit-gedit.theme         kellys.theme          pablo.theme         zenburn.theme
clarity.theme      edit-godot.theme         leo.theme             peaksea.theme       zmrok.theme
dante.theme        edit-jedit.theme         lucretia.theme        print.theme
darkblue.theme     edit-kwrite.theme        manxome.theme         rand01.theme
```

---

**Themes preview** [View as html](https://ecaudateduskydolphin.htmlpasta.com/)

[image: highlight linux all themes]

All theme preview generated with the below php code:

```
<?php
$themes = explode(".theme", `ls /usr/share/highlight/themes`);
foreach ($themes as $k=>$theme){
  $theme = trim($theme);
  system("echo '<hr><h3>$theme</h3>' >> all.html && highlight -l --out-format=xhtml --inline-css -s $theme --syntax=php < snippet.php 1>> all.html");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is called syntax highlighting.

[GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) when given a source file, produces a document with syntax highlighting.

I use the `lessfilter` script below, or you could make `less` invoke it automatically like with:

```
export LESSOPEN="| /path/to/lessfilter %s"
export LESS=' -R '
```

I found this [article](http://www.fpga-dev.com/getting-source-highlighting-in-the-linux-terminal/) and started doing it this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
file -b -L "$1" | grep -q text &&
  /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh "$1"
```

(`src-hilite-lesspipe.sh` is shipped with `source-highlight` but not all distributions include it)

Comment: "If you go to the article the author must be using a Mac since he uses capitals for his commands": I'm afraid you're a bit confused: Clearly you are not aware that `export` defines an environment variable, not an alias. The _command_ `less` uses flags from the environment variable `LESS`, so your answer needs some  work.